# Insert event with parent record external Id

Tags: apex

How Can I insert an **Event** object record with parent record external id?

> for Example for Contact object

```
Contact con = new Contact();
con.LastName = 'test123';
con.Account = new Account(
      ExtId__c='testExt');
insert con;
```

Comment: Do you want to assign the event to a contact?

Comment: @user40665. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you.

Comment: It could be a lead or contact @MartinLezer

Comment: I don't think it works with polymorphic fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you could do it, the pattern would be:

```
insert new Event(Who=new Contact(External__c = '54321'));
```

But that yields this error:

> Field is not writeable: Who

Same goes for `WhatId`:

```
insert new Event(What=new Account(Counsyl_ID__c = '54321'));
```

> Field is not writeable: What

That leads me to conclude that you cannot use the name pointing reference to set parent objects using External Id on a polymorphic relationship.